# Issue $_GET is empty

Tags: php, get

i have an issue with my code :

```
    <header class="page-header"><h1>Ajouter une salle</h1></header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <form action="creerSalle.php" method="get">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="numSalle">Numero salle :</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numSalle"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="numEtage">Numero étage (0 pour RDC) :</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numEtage"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="numBatiment">Numero bâtiment :</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numBatiment"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="typeSalle">Type salle :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="typeSalle"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="capacite">Capacite salle :</label>
                <input type="range" class="form-control" id="capacite" min="1" max="100"  onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);"/>
                <input type="text" id="textInput" value="" class="textRange" disabled/>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Valider"/>

        </form>

        <?php
            ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            print_r($_GET);

        if(!empty($_GET))
        {

            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projettutore', "root", "");
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO salle(id,numSalle,numEtage,numBatiment,typeSalle,capacite,nbOccupant) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,0)");

            $stmt->bindParam(1,$_GET["numSalle"],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(2,$_GET["numSalle"],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(3,$_GET["numEtage"],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(4,$_GET["numBatiment"],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(5,$_GET["typeSalle"],PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
            $stmt->bindParam(6,$_GET["capacite"],PDO::PARAM_INT);

            if($pdo->exec($sql)){
                echo "Insertion réussie !";
            }
            else
                echo "ERROR !";
        }   

        ?>

      </div>
    </div>
```

The $_GET variable is empty and the URL has no ? in it ..
I have no error and there is no insert in my database .
I can't figure what the problem is so can you help me please ?

Comment: you need to put the `name` attribute each of the input tag, so the get method can understand what to get.

Answer (score 1):

Using $_GET requires that the input field have a name attribute, so instead of

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numSalle"/>
```

you would have

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numSalle" name="numSalle"/>
```

Comment: It worked thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Add `name` attribute tu your form feilds .

```
     <input type="text" id="textInput" value="" class="textRange" name="FEILDNAME" disabled/>
```

NOTE: If u add disabled attribute `$_GET` variable not contain value of this field